# How to identify two legs of a sip call?

Tags: sip

I am developing a sip call tracking application. I have used Tag ID fields to connect the two call legs
 of a call. But some times tag ids will not be same.

What i have  done is  -

The tag ids are associated to a corresponding Call ID.

Is there any other field i need to consider for identifying legs(dialogues) of a call.

[image]
 The above one is an exmple for 1 call with tag ids. Different colors used for two legs. And the only similarity i have got  a number **3568450037** in tag id's. **10.10.10.120** is the server ip.

I have to find strong connection between the call legs. Please help me...
 And please suggest me some links to solve this issue..

thank u...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Call-ID, From tag and To tag are all that's used to identify a dialog. From the [SIP RFC chapter on Dialogs](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3261#section-12). The only trick is matching up local and remote tags, i.e. the To header tag at one end of the call matches the From header tag at the other end of the call and vice-versa.

> A dialog is identified at each UA with a dialog ID, which consists of
> a Call-ID value, a local tag and a remote tag.  The dialog ID at each
> UA involved in the dialog is not the same.  Specifically, the local
> tag at one UA is identical to the remote tag at the peer UA.  The
> tags are opaque tokens that facilitate the generation of unique
> dialog IDs.

**Update:**

Following your edit with the table containing the IP addresses and tags there are two completely separate calls involved which each have their own dialog. I guess that your question was more along the lines of how to match two different dialogs from two separate calls rather than trying to match in-dialog transactions/requests.

There actually isn't anything in the SIP headers you can use to match two independent SIP dialogs to know that the calls have been bridged together. I assume you are working with a B2BUA since it's the only common SIP element that bridges calls. One way to match the dialogs is to look into the SDP carried in the INVITE requests and responses. At the very least you can get the port number each leg is sending and receiving on and match them that way.

Comment: But I have got a situation that, a common tag id found at different calls. So i coudn't  identify the actual call.

Comment: Tag ID's are meant to be unique'ish. A SIP stack shouldn't be re-using tag IDs on different calls. That would be a bug. However even if the tag ID was the same as another call as long as the Call-ID and/or From tags were different you'd have something to distinguish the different calls.

Comment: Tags are _never_ meant to be reused. Also, I suspect that if the B2BUA terminated the media plane there would be no generic way of identifying the two legs, without comparing the contents of every media stream going through the B2BUA.

Comment: Ya i am working with Sip B2BUA server. I think by considering sdp info i can group the call legs. Thank you all...

Answer (score 1):

A bit late of an answer, but in case it helps anybody else:

If you are the one writing the B2BUA application you can modify it to add a header to the messages on each leg with the same identifier, then that identifier identifies not just one leg but the whole call.

There is an informational IETF document that proposed just that:
https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-kaplan-dispatch-session-id-03